# PDO and MySQL type switching

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a field 'year' in table 1 which is defined as a VARCHAR(255) and I need to update 'num_years' in table 2 with the value of 'year'. 'num_years' is defined as an INT.

When I try to update 'num_years' with 'year' if 'year' is defined as 3 it works fine, but if I define 'year' as 'foo' it will update 'num_years' with 0.

When I used to use `mysql_query` functions it would generate an error about invalid column 'foo' or similar, but with PDO it doesn't throw an exception when I was expecting it to.

In this manner we want to ensure that 'num_years' is not updated with 0 if 'years' is numeric. Does PDO have anything built in that throws exception if this is the case?

I'm using PDO transactions and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Validate if its a string or not before you put it into your sql statement that way if your year from table1 consists of something like "1 year" you can explode or otherwise strip off the characters and the space and return just the 1 for insert into your int column in table 2.

Also doing it this way you can special handle events like text only in input field and set it as either a 0 or a -1 or something in your int field which you can later trap and validate on display to say "not specified" or something equivilent.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Yeah thats what I'm currently doing, I do a simple `throw new Exception('Variable is not an integer')` by running `!is_numeric` and catch that a level up. It was the best option I could come up with for a solution, but I still feel it would be better for PDO to pick up that kind of thing. After all, good old `mysql_query` could pick it up and that was basically wind-up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting a string variable to PDO you can insert something like `$delta = $year + 0`. If it is "foo" you get `$delta = 0` and adding this to `num_years` will not change them.

The other way is of course typecasting, so use `(int)$year`.

This should be done in PHP, not PDO.

Comment: But crucially, if I use `(int)$year` and run that through my query it still won't throw an exception a la `mysql_query` fashion?